# Memory interfacing problem

Tags: memory-access, memory-allocation

I've learnt that the memory interfacing problem is used when we need to connect a memory that has lesser number of locations to a processor that has more address lines.
For eg. Connecting memory chips with net memory of 8KB to a CPU that can handle 64KB.

Can someone please elucidate or explain what this is? Why can't I just connect a lower memory size chip to a CPU with more number of address lines?

Comment: Sorry, I've never heard that phrase before, and I'm not sure what it would mean to "use" a "problem".  I  suggest you [edit] your question to cite the source where you read that and include an excerpt/quotation that shows what you read.  However it looks like this is already answered by https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/107208/755.

Comment: I'm sorry, the other question that you've linked is what I meant here. I had no idea how to delete this question, so I just let it be. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.